# Global exception handling in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to implement a global exception handling with MVVM pattern. In my existing case, whenever an error is happening inside of ViewModel, the application does not crash, just "hides" the rest of bindings that happen after the code that caused the error (certainly this is very misleading for end user, and not true, and should never happen that way). I would not like to implement try catch for every operation in the viewModel, and I dont like the silent way of error exception, I would really love to implement a way for WPF app to handle global errors. Is there a way to do it with the MVVM?

Comment: When you say "error is happening inside ViewModel", what error exactely is that? Or are you referring to Binding Errors (`System.Windows.Data` errors)? How do you know the error is happening at all?

Comment: You mean like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: Well, to simplify the answer to your question, for testing purposes, I am calling throw new Exception(); in the middle of my ViewModel binding operation

Comment: Handling global exception with AppDomain.UnhandledException works for everything else except errors happening inside of ViewModel binding

Comment: When you say "in the middle of my ViewModel binding operation", do you mean a property getter or setter is throwing? If you could post some actual code it might help us to help you.

Comment: Yes, and I have already resolve the issue with the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException solution. I have posted the answer, thanks

Comment: I'm fighting with this right now.  I can't seem to catch Exceptions from a ViewModel property's setter using any of these mechanisms in WPF. I just tried the `FirstChangeException` and it does indeed work, however, in cases where I do catch the Exception and deal with it, it still raises that event.  I simply want all unhandled exceptions to be handled in an event so I can show an error message.  This post was very helpful, but not quite what I'm looking for.  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long battle finally I have found a very easily way to implement handling exceptions inside of ViewModel. While creating a BindingListener that inherits from DefaultTraceListener is certainly a great way to find your binding errors during the debug mode, this will not catch exceptions that have occurred inside a ViewModel when running solution is standard mode. But AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException will.

App.xaml.cs:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += new EventHandler<System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs>(CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException);


    private void CurrentDomain_FirstChanceException(object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred \n\r" + e.Exception.Message + "\n\r" + e.Exception.StackTrace, "ERROR", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error)));
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you want to gracefully handle ViewModel exceptions.

Comment: You are right. It works, but after a few months of working with it, I find it not to be the best way to handle ViewModel errors in my opinion as well. However, I did not find any other better solution, would you perhaps know any other way to handle ViewModel exceptions?

Comment: I have to admit that I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. "Handling" exceptions globally is rarely a good idea in any program, but it actually seems like you're trying to manage exceptions thrown during _binding_ to a ViewModel, which I assume means property getters and setters. If so, the standard advice would be: getters should never throw, and setter failures can be managed (to an extent) via mechanisms such as IDataErrorInfo. Either way your ViewModel (locally) needs to understand what could go wrong and deal with it if it can. Do you have some specific example code?

Comment: Thanks for the valuable input. I agree with you, I should catch potential ViewModel exceptions and deal with them accordingly. To be honest, I wanted to save time during the development, and instead of dealing with potentials errors within getters and setters, I have decided to rely on global exception that will notify me in order to fix unanticipated errors. It is internal app, so not too big of a deal, once I resolve all those errors, the exception should never be thrown again. I always implement global exception handling as last chance to deal with errors, and notify the developer and user.

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap each method in a lamba.  Something like this...

```
        public async void DoSomething()
        {
            await RunSafe(async () =>
            {
                await model.DoSomething();
                await model.DoSomethingElse();
                await model.DoLastThing();
            });
        }
        private async Task RunSafe(Func<Task> del, [CallerMemberName] String methodName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info("Executing {0}", methodName);
                await del();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusMessage = string.Format("Error in {0}(...): {1}\r\n{2}", methodName, ex.Message, ex.ToString());                

                Log.Error("Error occured in plug in.", ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into deriving the `DefaultTraceListener` class. I've seen people derive their own `BindingListener` from it, and override the `WriteLine` method to throw your own exceptions.

You can just spin one of these up during your application start, and it should go on it's own:

```
public class BindingListener : DefaultTraceListener`
{
    public BindingListener()
    {
        PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
        PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(this);SourceLevels.Error;
    }
    public override void WriteLine(string message){...}
}
```

Note: This may not do *exactly* what you want out of the box, you may have to modify a few props.

Comment: So I was able to implement the DefaultTraceListener, and that works great while I am in the debug mode, but when I run the application in release, binding errors are not being caught. Is there a way to override that, so the DefaultTraceListener will still run in the Release mode; and how about the performance, it will be slower as well, right?

Comment: As far as performance goes, you'd have to test it, but I can't imagine the any performance difference would be significant.

As for release mode, you could try this: `PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.All`.
However, I'm not sure if WPF actually raises Binding errors to a level you can see on a release build.